# Java Temporary Files, read and write

Tags: java, file, temp

I have this piece of code

```
package Classes;

import java.io.*;

public class IpAdministrator {

    public Boolean isActive(String ipAddress) {
        boolean isActive = false;
        String cmd;
        String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
        System.out.println(OS);
        String tmpfolder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        System.out.println(tmpfolder);

        //iptmp.deleteOnExit();

        if (OS.equals("Linux")) {
            cmd = "ping " + ipAddress + " -c 1";
        } else {
            cmd = "cmd /c ping " + ipAddress + " -n 1";
        }
        try {
            String s = null;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            File iptmp = File.createTempFile("ipresult", ".txt", new File(tmpfolder));


            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));


            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
                s = s.toString();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(iptmp));
                writer.write(s);

            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage().toString());
        }


        return isActive;
    }

}
```

I want to write the result from the command in the temporary file, I found something related in other questions in this site, and it seems to work fine, but when I run this, the file is created with some random numers (ie: ipresult540677216848957037.txt) and it's empty, I can't figure out why, I also read that it's something related to java 1.7, so that means that I can't fill the file with information, there something that I'm missing?

Comment: I think it is because you didn't call writer.flush() or close the writer,so the content is stil in buffer.

Comment: `s = s.toString()` accomplishes precisely nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you open a file for writing that way -- i.e., every time you execute this line:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(iptmp));
```

the file is truncated to zero length. Furthermore, since you never explicitly call `close()` on the `BufferedWriter`, line you do write will never actually be flushed to the file. As a result, no data ever makes it to the disk.

To do this correctly, first, move the line above to before the loop, so it only executes once. Second, after the loop, include code like

```
if (writer != null)
    writer.close();
```

Finally, note that your program is needlessly broken on Macs, which are neither Linux, nor do they use `cmd.exe`. Instead of the way you've written this, you test explicitly for Windows, and use the Windows command line if you find it; otherwise, assume something UNIX-like, and use the Linux version.

Answer (score -5):

You need to close the writer

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(iptmp));
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.toString();
        writer.write(s);
    }

} finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

If you are using java 7

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
        iptmp));) {

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.toString();
        writer.write(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's only one part of the problem.

Comment: I tried to understand both answers, and this is how I finally got it:

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(iptmp));
  
  
  try
  {
   while ((s = stdInput.readLine())!=null)
   {
    System.out.println(s); 
    writer.write(s+"\r\n");
    
   }
  }
  finally
  {
   if (writer !=null)
   {
    writer.close();
   }
  }

btw, @Ernest you are right ,  I'm just testing on windows.

Comment: @user1216761 as Ernest Friedman-Hill said your code will work only in windows not in linux

Comment: Yes, it does solve the problem, after you copied the other part of the solution from my answer.

Comment: no, the initial one was a short answer, while I was still editing it

Comment: any java dev will know abt using try..catch block while handling resources